# Struts2-jquery plug-in's tags with Jquery is not working when used together

Tags: jquery

I need to enable and disable the struts2-Jquery spinner using
struts2-jquery radio button. how to achieve this. Below is what the
code written in my own way but it fails to enable or disable.

**jquery**

```
$("#Edit_Sub_Stage_Order_ID").click(function(){
      $("#spinner3").removeAttr("disabled"); 
    });
```

**struts2-jquery tags inside body**

```
<sj:radio
                    id="Edit_Sub_Stage_Order_ID"
                    label="Edit Sub Stage Order"
                    list="{'Enable'}"
                    name="Edit_Sub_Stage_Order"

            />

<sj:spinner  
        id="spinner3" 
        value="1"
        min="1" 
        max="2"  
        mouseWheel="true"
        label="Edit Sub Stage"
        disabled="true"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this will not work until unless we use the proper Id of struts2-jquery. Because the will create a Id prefixing with their some bal bal and our Id. So i suggest to see the view page source in your browser and find the Id created by struts2-jquery and use it in where ever you needed it.